# box-sizing: borderbox; should prevent side scroll?

Tags: html, css, widescreen

Im currently doing The Odin Project and my asignment was to make the Google homepage. iv'e come across a problem that I do not know how to solve. I thought by adding the box-sizing: borderbox; the page would not extend larger than the screen im using curenlty is. With other words my google page is super wide. Here is my project on github: https://github.com/JohnEnglund/google-homepage

Comment: You should post your code here in a snippet (button [<>] ) .Aside , You are not using position:relative properly or at least misunderstand how it works.,

Answer (score 0):

The `box-sizing: borderbox;` property works differently than you thought. Accordingly to [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp):

> The box-sizing property defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.

> border-box: The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border

So, adding this property to your CSS just give the browser the ability (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)):

> to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width. This typically makes it much easier to size elements.

To finish, if your page is super wide is because of some wrong configuration in your CSS file. Try to **add background color in your elements** to see how wide they are. This is a good debugging tool for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the border box property, but with the width of your inner elements. The main issue is your method of positioning the elements. You should avoid defining top, right etc positions in pixels. Instead use margins and try reducing width of your elements if they are an issue:
Here are some modifications I made:

- style.css

```
header {
  display: flex;
  /* width: 90%; */
  height: 4.8vh;
  /* margin: auto; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-pic {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* left: 92%; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 4.8vh;
}

/* .burger-menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 1080px;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 1072px; 
} */

.logo img {
  height: 92px;
  width: 272px;
  margin:auto;
  /* text-align: center; */
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 47px;
  /* position: relative; */
  text-align: center;
  /* left: 500px; */
  top: 25px;
}

.language {
  font-size: small;
  position: relative;
  /* left: 590px; */
  text-align: center;
}

.ending {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  /* right: 880px; */
  flex: 2;
  padding-left : 50px;
}
.btm-navlinks {
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

Add a div wrapper around header elements to shift them right:

- index.html

```
    <header>
      <div class="header-wrap">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a class="nav-link1" href="#">Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link2" href="#">Bilder</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="burger-menu">
          <a href="#"
            ><img
              class="burger-menulink"
              src="./Pictures/Skärmavbild 2020-07-07 kl. 17.33.43.png"
              alt="burger-menu"
          /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-pic">
          <a href="#"
            ><img
              class="profile-pic"
              src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADGmqu_I3j_aWjRLGl97SmvJwotO5yAsUOC4AmXnL7MK=s192-c-mo"
              alt="profile picture"
          /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

- style.css

```
.header-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  right:2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also it is not a good practice to add images externally on input text, try background property instead

- style.css

```
.form-control-search {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 24px;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url(./Pictures/mglass.svg), url(./Pictures/voice_icon.svg);
  background-position: left, right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
  padding:0 4% ;
}
.form-control-search:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px #dfe1e5;
}

/* .mglass-pic svg {
  height: 3vh;
}
.mglass-pic {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 360px;
  width: 3vh;
} */

/* .icon svg {
  height: 5vh;
}
.icon svg {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 122px;
  left: 890px;
  width: 4vh;
} */
```

Remove the divs of images, and add a button wrapper around your buttons:-

- index.html

```
      <form
        action="https://www.google.com/search"
        class="search-form"
        method="get"
        name="serachform"
        target="_blank"
      >
        <input name="sitesearch" type="hidden" />
        <input
          type="text"
          autocomplete="on"
          class="form-control-search"
          name="q"
          required
        />
        <div class="button-wrap">
          <button class="button" type="submit">Sök på Google</button>
          <button class="button" type="submit">Jag har tur</button>
        </div>  
      </form>
<!-- <div class="mglass-pic">
        <svg
          focusable="false"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        >
          <path
            d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="icon">
        <svg
          class="HPVvwb"
          focusable="false"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            d="m12 15c1.66 0 3-1.31 3-2.97v-7.02c0-1.66-1.34-3.01-3-3.01s-3 1.34-3 3.01v7.02c0 1.66 1.34 2.97 3 2.97z"
            fill="#4285f4"
          ></path>
          <path d="m11 18.08h2v3.92h-2z" fill="#34a853"></path>
          <path
            d="m7.05 16.87c-1.27-1.33-2.05-2.83-2.05-4.87h2c0 1.45 0.56 2.42 1.47 3.38v0.32l-1.15 1.18z"
            fill="#f4b400"
          ></path>
          <path
            d="m12 16.93a4.97 5.25 0 0 1 -3.54 -1.55l-1.41 1.49c1.26 1.34 3.02 2.13 4.95 2.13 3.87 0 6.99-2.92 6.99-7h-1.99c0 2.92-2.24 4.93-5 4.93z"
            fill="#ea4335"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </div> -->
```

- style.css

```
.button-wrap{
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

also save the two svg images in Pictures folder, named mglass.svg and voice_icon.svg

And you are good to go....

PS :- use `position:relative` only when required